# Create point on a line with given distance from end in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, geometry, linestring, linear-referencing

Does anyone know how to create points along a line (MultiLineString geometry) with a given distance in PostGIS? I'd like to create points at a regular distance over a line, which represents a shoreline.

Comment: You're talking to some degree about linear referencing. Might be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107277/ and related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23674/

Answer (score 2):

Use [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html)

union them first to create a single complete without gaps line .

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
CREATE TABLE coastalsegments AS (SELECT ST_Line_Substring(the_geom, 1000.00*n/length,
   CASE WHEN 1000.00*(n+1) < length THEN 1000.00*(n+1)/length ELSE 1 END) As the_geom
FROM
  (SELECT ST_LineMerge(coastal_shoreline.geom) AS the_geom, ST_Length(coastal_shoreline.geom) As length
   FROM coastal_shoreline)
   ) AS t
CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,10000) AS n
WHERE n*1000.00/length < 1);

ALTER TABLE coastalsegments ADD id bigserial, ADD segm_length real;

UPDATE coastalsegments SET segm_length = ST_Length(the_geom);

CREATE TABLE coastal_pts AS SELECT id, ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(the_geom, 0.5) AS the_geom FROM  coastalsegments;
```

Comment: This should probably be made into an edit ("added solution") to your original post, and accept nicves's answer.